# How are we able to call a function to typecast on a custom type even when a method is not defined to it

Tags: go, casting, primitive

How could we call a function on hello as hello(0) below even though we have no function defined on hello?

```
package main
import "fmt"
type hello int32

func main() {
    x := hello(0)
    //converting int to int32
    fmt.Printf("Type : %T, Value: %v", x, x) //prints "Type : main.hello, Value: 0"
}
```

Comment: see [Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types): "*A type definition creates a new, distinct type with the same underlying type and operations as the given type, and binds an identifier to it.*" So since you can call `int32(0)`, you can also call `hello(0)`.

Comment: Note that Go doesn't actually support typeasting.  What you've demonstrated is a type conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Well I see type "hello" has got the properties of int32. I was looking to find source code for the implementation of type int32 in golang source code. I found this https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5203357ebacf9f41ca5e194d953c164049172e96/src/builtin/builtin.go#L48.
But even this doesn't have the actual implementation. Can someone direct me to the source code of int32 in golang?

Answer (score 2):

I highly suggest you to take a look at [Types in Go](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types).

Also, to set a variable to a custom type, you have to declare it manually.

In this case, it should be `var x hello = 0`

```golang
package main
import "fmt"

type hello int32

func main() {
    var x hello = 0 // converting int to hello
    fmt.Printf("Type : %T, Value: %v", x, x) // prints "Type: main.hello, Value: 0"
}
```

Now to convert a numeric type to `hello` type, use the `hello(x)` function (it's already built-in since you have the custom `hello` type)

Let's suppose you have the following code:

```golang
package main
import "fmt"

type hello int32

func main() {
    var x int = 0
    fmt.Printf("Type : %T, Value: %v", x, x) // prints "Type: int, Value: 0"
}
```

Here, we will convert `x` to `hello` type. To do it, just use `hello(x)`.

```golang
package main
import "fmt"

type hello int32

func main() {
    var x int = 0
    y := hello(x) // converting 'x' to 'hello' type
    fmt.Printf("Type : %T, Value: %v", y, y) // prints "Type: main.hello, Value: 0"
}
```